# При запуске telegram бота на сервере отваливается поток отвечающий за обработку команд и их ответ

Tags: многопоточность, telegram-bot, kotlin, telegram, telegrambots

При чем именно при запуске на сервере. Локально все работает без проблем. Вот ошибка, которую выдает в логах

```
Exception in thread "OkHttp Dispatcher" kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property telegramUpdateHandler has not been initialized
```

Comment: Используете ли вы kapt?

Comment: Нет, не использую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно, вы объявили переменную и пообещали ее инициализировать позже, но не сделали этого.

Данная ошибка говорит, что вы обращаетесь к переменной которая ещё не инициализирована.

Если объявить переменную

`lateinit var variable: Int`

Перед обращением к этой переменной она должна быть инициализирована

`variable = 1// или другое число...`

В противном случае будет эксепшен как у Вас.

Comment: 1. А почему тогда бот работал локально без каких-либо проблем?
2. Почему до этого, бот несколько месяцев работал также на сервере и такой ошибки не возникало?
3. Могу ли я оставить так, как сделал или это может привести к другим ошибкам?

Comment: Возможно, до этого дня вы не обращались к этой переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло это. Не знаю насколько это допустимо, но теперь бот также работает и на сервере.

```
//    private lateinit var telegramUpdateHandler: TelegramUpdateHandler
var telegramUpdateHandler: TelegramUpdateHandler? = null
```